# File Manipulation with pandas

Tags: python, file-manipulation

I am a beginner in manipulating files, hence I haven't got a full grasp of it. What I want to do is, by using pandas, create a new file that has all the elements of a previews one listed based on their price in descending order. This is my code:

```
file = pandas.read_csv('list_of_items.csv', skiprows=1)
sorted_file = file.sort_values(by = 'price', ascending=False)
sorted_file.to_csv('items_sorted_price.csv', index=False)
```

However I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\arcal\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__ 
  self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 529, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 749, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

What can I do to solve the problem?
Where would you recommend a beginner like me to start working in order to grasp better this topic?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There problem is another encoding of data than default. By default `pandas.read_csv` expects `utf-8` encoding. And error says that it can't decode symbol in file using this encoding. So you need to find which one was used for creating that file.
I suppose `cp1251` as very common.

```
pd.read_csv('list_of_items.csv', skiprows=1 encoding="cp1251")
```

About some starting point for pandas - there are a lot of cool tutorials about it. For example from official documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html
You can find another just googling `pandas 101`.

Comment: I check the Internet for tutorials all the time, however I always ask someone more experienced before deciding. Thanks a lot for your advice, I'll stick with the docs.

Comment: @Klaiv_Mrt feel free to ask :) SO created for that

Answer (score 1):

When Pandas reads a CSV, it defaults to reading it with `utf-8` encoding, however, there are other encoding formats that could be used. The `read_csv` function can take the encoding format as a parameter.

Here is the code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

There are many different formats you can try, here is full [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). I would recommend opening the file with notepad, or another text editor, and then save as a CSV with a utf-8 encoding.

---

If you only have to read a few csv file, you can use the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', engine='python')
```

Comment: The issue was at the file. When I opened it with notepad, I saw a bunch of gibberish thus the utf-8 encoding couldn't decode it. I just changed the format of the file and it worked just fine. Thank you !!!